# Build AOSP custom rom

Tags: android, build, android-source, selinux

I'm trying to build enforcing, but I had 7 violations. How can I fix?

```
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 5 of device/motorola/sanders/sepolicy/vendor/ims.te (or line 75926 of
 policy.conf) violated by allow hal_camera_default hal_camera_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 3 of device/motorola/sanders/sepolicy/vendor/hal_nfc_default.te (or l
ine 75741 of policy.conf) violated by allow hal_secure_element_default hal_secure_element_hwservice:hwservice_man
ager { add };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 3 of device/motorola/sanders/sepolicy/vendor/hal_nfc_default.te (or l
ine 75741 of policy.conf) violated by allow rild hal_secure_element_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 5 of system/sepolicy/public/hal_secure_element.te (or line 15685 of p
olicy.conf) violated by allow hal_nfc_default hal_secure_element_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 5 of system/sepolicy/public/hal_camera.te (or line 14186 of policy.co
nf) violated by allow init hal_camera_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 521 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 10809 of policy.conf
) violated by allow hal_fingerprint_default default_android_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 519 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 10807 of policy.conf
) violated by allow qseeproxy default_android_service:service_manager { add };
libsepol.check_assertions: 7 neverallow failures occurred
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with `neverallow` violations: You have a rule that says "Never allow type `x` to do `action` on some other type/class `y:c`" and then another rule that says "This subtype of `x` is allowed to do `action` on `y:c`". The SE Linux compiler will reject these contradictory rules. This can be solved by modifying the `neverallow` rule to make an exception for the specific subtype you want to allow.

More precisely, if you have rules of the form:

1. `neverallow x y:c action;`
2. `type z, x;` (meaning `z` is a special case of `x`)
3. `allow z y:c action;`

Modify the first rule to `neverallow {x -z} y:class action;` to make an exception for the subtype `z`.

Example:

1. [Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/android10-dev/private/domain.te#171): `neverallow { domain ... -installd} staging_data_file:dir *;` says objects of type `domain` should not be allowed to access objects of type `staging_data_file` and class `dir`. However, it makes an exception for type `installd`.
2. [Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/master/public/installd.te#2): `type installd, domain;` defines `installd` to be a special case of `domain`.
3. [Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/master/private/installd.te#42): `allow installd staging_data_file:dir { open ... };` allows `installd` to do action `open` on objects of type `staging_data_file` and class `dir`.

Comment: Thank you very much, friend. But I cannot modify the source. I need to make modifications on trees. It's possible?

Comment: Do you mean you can modify device/* but not system/* (as I understand it, you are applying some custom patch or you added some custom files for a Motorola device)? In that case, you could try the approach someone gave in this answer (making the allow rules you add more specific so they don't trigger the neverallow violations): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956629/need-some-guide-with-a-android-selinux-build-error/58989518#58989518