# Need some Guide with a Android SELinux Build Error

Tags: android, build, selinux

im currently trying to compile Android 9 with an Quectel EC25 LTE on the RockPi 4.
But currently i'm stuck at the SELinux implementation. 
The EC25 RIL Guide tells me to modify/add the following Files to the src tree.

- ($Android_src)/system/core/rootdir/ueventd.rc

```
#quectel port
/dev/ttyUSB* 0660 radio radio
/dev/cdc-wdm* 0660 radio radio
/dev/qcqmi* 0660 radio radio
/dev/cdc-acm* 0660 radio radio
```

- ($Android_src)/external/sepolicy/file_contexts

```
/dev/ttyUSB[0-9]* u:object_r:tty_device:s0
/dev/ttyACM[0-9]* u:object_r:tty_device:s0
/system/bin/rild u:object_r:rild_exec:s0
/system/socket/rild u:object_r:rild_socket:s0
/system/socket/rild-debug u:object_r:rild_debug_socket:s0
/system/bin/pppd u:object_r:pppd_exec:s0
/dev/ppp u:object_r:ppp_device:s0
```

- ($Android_src)/external/sepolicy/rild.te

```
allow rild default_prop:property_service set;
allow rild device:chr_file { read write ioctl open getattr };
allow rild kernel:system module_request;
allow rild net_radio_prop:property_service set;
allow rild ppp_device:chr_file { read write ioctl open };
allow rild ppp_exec:file { read execute open execute_no_trans };
allow rild radio_prop:property_service set;
allow rild self:capability { net_admin setuid };
allow rild shell_exec:file { read execute open execute_no_trans };
allow rild sysfs_wake_lock:file { open read write };
allow rild system_file:file execute_no_trans;
allow rild system_prop:property_service set;
```

after running make i get the following Error:

```
FAILED: out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy
/bin/bash -c "(ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy -M -c             30 -o out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.recovery.conf ) && (out/host/linux-x86/bin/sepolicy-analyze out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp permissive > out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains ) && (if [ \"userdebug\" = \"user\" -a -s out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains ]; then          echo \"==========\" 1>&2;               echo \"ERROR: permissive domains not allowed in user builds\" 1>&2;             echo \"List of invalid domains:\" 1>&2;               cat out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains 1>&2;           exit 1;                 fi ) && (mv out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy )"
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 532 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 10484 of policy.conf) violated by allow rild default_prop:property_service { set };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 418 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 10370 of policy.conf) violated by allow rild device:chr_file { read write open };
libsepol.check_assertions: 2 neverallow failures occurred
Error while expanding policy
out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy:  loading policy configuration from out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy.recovery_intermediates/sepolicy.recovery.conf
[  4% 449/10291] build out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows
FAILED: out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows ) && (ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy -M -c               30 -o out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/policy.conf )"
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 532 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 10425 of policy.conf) violated by allow rild default_prop:property_service { set };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 418 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 10311 of policy.conf) violated by allow rild device:chr_file { read write open };
libsepol.check_assertions: 2 neverallow failures occurred
Error while expanding policy
out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy:  loading policy configuration from out/target/product/rk3399/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/policy.conf
[  4% 450/10291] //bionic/libc:libc_bionic_ndk clang++ bionic/bionic_systrace.cpp [arm]
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
10:24:06 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

i'm not familiar with Android/SELinux but i googled about the error and found "neverallow" directives to be set without any luck.

Help would be appreciated,

rgds

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210696/build-aosp-custom-rom/58211402#58211402

Comment: after adding “-rild” to the lines:

system/sepolicy/public/domain.te :418
neverallow { domain -rild } device:chr_file { open read write };

system/sepolicy/public/domain.te :523
neverallow { domain -init -vendor_init -rild } default_prop:property_service set;

i receive following error:

system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:418:ERROR ‘unknown type rild’ at token ‘;’ on line 10295:
neverallow { domain -rild } device:chr_file { open read write };

Comment: Ok, that's strange. The existing source in system/sepolicy has other mentions of rild, right? Does it have "type rild, domain;" somewhere?

Comment: i checked folder "system/sepolicy/*" for files containing "type rild, domain;"
system/sepolicy/vendor/rild.te
system/sepolicy/prebuilts/api/26.0/public/rild.te
system/sepolicy/prebuilts/api/27.0/public/rild.te

thats all in /system/sepolicy/*

Comment: this problem is resolved ?? i am also facing same issue.

Comment: I have this same issue. Do you have a specific fix?

Answer (score 2):

Your allow rules are too generic for Android.

The neverallow rules are quite well documented. Look  at `system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:532` and `system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:418` from your error message:

```
# Require that domains explicitly label unknown properties, and do not allow
# anyone but init to modify unknown properties.
neverallow { domain -init -vendor_init } default_prop:property_service set;
```

```
# Don't allow raw read/write/open access to generic devices.
# Rather force a relabel to a more specific type.
neverallow domain device:chr_file { open read write };
```

You need to find out which properties `rild` has to set and then add a more specific allow rule. Check if existing `property_contexts` files already assign a type to the properties `rild` needs or create them yourself.
The same needs to be done for the devices `rild` wants to access.

**Note**: There are macros at `system/sepolicy/public/te_macros` which would make your `rild.te` more readable. Example: replace `allow rild default_prop:property_service set` with `set_prop(rild, default_prop)`.